# Error with radiobuttons in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 radio buttons 1.open 2.confidential to department 3.selected to restricted users and I have a list below where all the users name will display in that list box.

How to connect those radio buttons with users list for example I select restricted to selected users and select 2users in list box those users cannot see the data but what my problem is when I select users and restricted to selected users but still they can view the data how to link this radiobuttons and list.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rbSecurityLevel" runat="server">
    <asp:listitem id="option1" runat="server" value="Open" />
    <asp:listitem id="option2" runat="server" value="Confidential to Department" />
 <asp:listitem id="option3" runat="server" value="Restricted to Selected Users" />
</asp:radiobuttonlist >
```